# Changing Windows' perceived native resolution

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, resolution, edid

Is there any way of changing Windows' perceived native resolution?

The reason for asking, is that I would like to use 1440x900 resolution on my retina macbook (2880x1800 native), in order to achieve the 2x pixel perfect effect.

Setting the resolution to 1440x900 the normal way through windows, causes windows to use linear interpolation, as It's not "aware" that the selected resolution is actually exactly pixel perfect, and as such, blurs the image.

I understand this information is hard coded in the display's EDID, and that you can override this information in the registry. Is it possible to "fool" windows into seeing the monitor as a 1440x900 res monitor, and not 2880x1800 somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look over http://superuser.com/questions/3057/force-native-resolution-to-non-pnp-monitor-in-windows?rq=1, it might have some useful ideas for you to work with.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that last solution with the phoenix software, but unfortunately, it didn't work. Windows still detected 2880x1800 as the native and recommended resolution, and therefore blurs 1440x900. Anyone? :)

Answer (score 0):

Window's "perceived" native resolution comes from what is reported to it by the graphics hardware driver (which, except in Windows Safe Mode, is usually not a Windows component). Likewise, it is entirely the responsibility of the graphics card/chip driver
to accept a requested monitor resolution output and adjust it's hardware to do exactly that in a reasonable manner. In other words: it is not Windows that is scaling the graphics output in an undesirable manner, it is the video driver. My own Intel 945G chip driver software is very buggy, and can not output monitor resolutions smaller than the "native" resolution in a correct manner. If I instead compose a Detailed Timing Descriptor (in accordance with VESA specifications), and force the driver to use that, the display is perfect. You do not mention the video driver you're using, but I would suggest looking into its options for
custom resolution output, and scaling method choices. You might also try keeping your monitor resolution at native, and adjust the Windows "DPI" setting to twice its actual value on your monitor.