# Titan Black resolution issues - can't move above 1024x768

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, hp-proliant

I have a Titan Black card in an HP DL380p server computer. I am having an issue I believe is related to HDCP but I'm not sure.

The rack has a LCD monitor that can support up to 1920x1200. With other computers in the rack I can go up to that resolution. It comes up on the other computers as a Generic Non-PnP Monitor.

With the Titan Black, it will only let me show up to 1024x768. I can force the resolution to be higher in the NVidia panel but it comes up on the screen fuzzy (unlike from the other computers). I've already tested all the wires.

It does come up as a Non-HDCP monitor, and a Generic PnP Monitor. When I connect an HDCP monitor, it will show the higher resolution options from the same ports. I'm only trying to get Windows to the higher resolution, I'm not sourcing any media that should trigger HDCP.

Can anyone think of reasons it might be behaving that way? How can I get my resolution higher out of the Titan Black to this monitor? (The resolution is important for a Unity program, I really need 1920x1080 on the screen, but I haven't even gotten to the point of opening the app yet.)

Thanks!

ETA: Let me explain a little more about my setup, because it is unusual:
I have two DVIs coming out of this card, one goes straight to a KVM and one goes to a BlackBox KVM Fiber Extender and then the passthrough goes to another KVM port. The BlackBox extended screen goes to a large monitor that is guest/player facing.

When the outside monitor is on and the local one unplugged, it displays at 1920x1080 with no trouble. When it is plugged back into the local KVM, it forces the resolution low again. We need it to show on both so that the status can be checked from backstage. The big monitor registers as HDCP compliant and the small one does not. From other computers plugged into the same KVM, we can get 1920x1080 without issue.

Comment: Just covering the basics, is the screen plugged into the correct port? Have you got the latest drivers installed?

Comment: Yes to all of the above. It is plugged into a KVM and a media extender on the two DVI ports.

Comment: If OS detects monitor as "Non-HDCP" or "Generic PnP" there are no drivers for this monitor installed...

Comment: Yeah. The monitor doesn't have any specific drivers though (it is a generic rack mount LCD) and that isn't a problem on the other computers either. The model is "Rackmount WUXGA 17" LCD Monitor - 7U".

Comment: You can try to determine if it is an EDID handshake issue: http://www.extron.com/product/software.aspx?id=8482 http://www.extron.com/company/article.aspx?id=uedid

Comment: And SU one: http://superuser.com/questions/3057/force-native-resolution-to-non-pnp-monitor-in-windows | Have you tried switch GPU DVIs?