Windows 10 - how to force monitor to be recognised as NON PNP
This might be a strange question, but I'm looking for a way to force Windows 10 to recognise a plug-n-play display as a non PNP display...?
It's a long tale, but the TL;DR is I'm working on upgrading a bespoke kiosk system from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Windows 7 was happy to work with the display at 1024x768, but Windows 10 insists on restricting the resolution to 800x600. (1024x768 is important for the design of the software.)
I've discovered the EDID block from the display does allow 1024x768 so it's possible the Basic Display Adapter for Windows 10 doesn't allow 1024x768?
The reason I'm asking about a non PNP monitor is that we also have another kiosk with a different display hardware utilising a DVI<>VGA connection (don't know if that's relevant), and Windows 10 recognises it as non PNP monitor, and does allows 1024x768 (plus a few other resolutions), so perhaps it's not the display driver limiting the resolution.
I've found a hardware way to disable EDID (https://superuser.com/a/12080/10980), not tried that yet, and I've discovered there is an ability to override EDIDs via a .inf file, but I don't know if the software route can effectively disable the EDID?

You should try the possible solution then edit your question accordingly

Thanks Ramhound, I'd like to explore both solutions in parallel.  A hardware change is the more expensive route for the business (with over 400 kiosks in service!), so I'd like to explore a potential software solution at the same time.

The solution described in the duplicate is likely your only viable option
